# I want to return specific number of records based on condition using Laravel join

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a google form clone using Laravel 8.0

My table structure is as follows:

**1 surveys**

1. ID
2. survey_name
3. survey_description
4. survey_type
5. start_date
6. end_date

**2. projects**

1. id
2. project_name
3. project_description
4. company_id

**3. companies**

1. id
2. company_name
3. company_address

I wrote code to return projects as follows:

```
$projects = \DB::table('projects')
                ->join('companies', 'projects.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                ->select('projects.*', 'companies.company_name as company_name',
                    \DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM surveys WHERE DATE(surveys.end_date) < "'.date('Y-m-d').'" AND surveys.project_id = projects.id) as completed_surveys'),
                    \DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM surveys WHERE surveys.project_id = projects.id) as total_surveys') 
                )
                ->paginate(6);
```

Now I want to return only those projects where **total_surveys** = **completed_surveys**.

Please guide me.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Done....

**Below is the code work for me...**

```
 $projects = \DB::table('projects')->where(
                \DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM surveys WHERE DATE(surveys.end_date) < "'.date('Y-m-d').'" AND surveys.project_id = projects.id)'),
                \DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM surveys WHERE surveys.project_id = projects.id)')
            )
                ->join('companies', 'projects.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                ->select('projects.*', 'companies.company_name as company_name',
                    \DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM surveys WHERE DATE(surveys.end_date) < "'.date('Y-m-d').'" AND surveys.project_id = projects.id) as completed'),
                    \DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM surveys WHERE surveys.project_id = projects.id) as total_surveys') 
                )
                ->paginate(6);
```